# How to Find, remove and show counter via SSH?

Tags: ssh, command-line

I want to run a command which searches for specific files, then removes them then show how many already is deleted. So far I was using:

```
find -type f -name "*.cache" -exec rm {} \;
```

but when I have over 400k files, I'd like to know how much already was deleted like:

```
1 - file1234.cache
2 - file121342.cache
3 - file15467.cache
4 - file1678534.cache
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will satisfy you

```
find -type f -name "*.cache" -exec rm -v {} + | nl
```